# Most convenient way to work with local go dependencies?

Tags: go, dependencies, vgo

I'm wondering how to work with local libraries. Let's say I want to develop two vgo projects in parallel, a `my-project` and a `my-util` project which is used by `my-project`. Of course `my-util` is available at a remote repository, but since it's not feasible to commit all my changes in here into the master branch just to make them available (and testable) in `my-project`, I want to use the local version of `my-util` instead. Similar to the good old `mvn clean install` in Java.

I figure this must be realized with the `replace` directive. But this means that I need to manipulate my `go.mod` in `my-project` in a way I don't want to commit later. Is there any way around this problem except removing all my `replace` directives before the commit and just to re-add them afterwards?

Is there something like a `go_local.mod` which contains the `replace` directives and could be put on `.gitignore`? Or some kind of environment variable where I can define replacements? Or at least an IDE which allows to ignore `replace` directives in the `go.mod` on commit?

Or am I taking the wrong approach and is there a more convenient alternative for the `replace` approach in my case?

Comment: No. Just use `replace` and don't commit the temporary change to repo.

Comment: [`git add -p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--p). I never use add without -p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Go comes up with better solution finally. With 1.18 it is possible to create a workplace file where `replace` directives can be applied: https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/45713-workspace.md

So a `go.work` like this should work:

```
go 1.18

use (
    ./my-project // location of the go.mod of my project
)

replace github.com/NotX/my-util => ./my-util // location of go.mod
```

So starting from the `go.work` file location the command `go test ./my-project/...` should now use the local utility repo.

1.18 isn't release yet though, so that might change bit.